# External jquery file is not working in spring MVC?

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

My Jsp is ,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%-- <%@include file="include.jsp"%> --%>

<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="../tld/spring-form.tld" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/hello.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<%out.println("Hello") ;%>
 <form:form  commandName="person">
        Select A or B :
        <form:input path="option" id="option" />
        <input type="button" value="Ajax Submit" onclick="hello();">

        <p id = "result"></p>

</form:form> 
</body>
</html>
```

`out.println("Hello")` is printed in browser and the form also displayed.Only the external Jquery is not working to do javaScript call.

My dispatcher-Servlet will be,

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

My external hello.js contains ,

```
function hello(){
    alert("Hello 99");
    var val = $("#option").val();
    alert("Option : "+val);
}
```

My project structure is ,

[image]

When I click the button I get this in the console

```
Apr 8, 2013 9:03:08 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SampleChat/jquery/hello.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Apr 8, 2013 9:03:09 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SampleChat/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

I need to call the JavaScript function to get the alert .

Good answers are definitely appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any `<script>` elements in your jsp. You need to include the javascript scripts by referencing them in a `<script>` element.

Comment: you may have to remove slashes in src like this

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/hello.js"></script>

Comment: I added the external script. See     `<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>` and 
    `<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/hello.js"></script>`

Comment: Removed the slash and still not working.

Comment: What's not working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: @ Colin  I am getting the `Object expected` error in browser.

Comment: Try to edit source src="../jquery/hello.js">

Comment: @Givi Tried and no use...

Comment: src="webcontent/jquery/hello.js" try this last idea ;)

Comment: Thanks but still no use.Can um please upvote my question so that it can make some research by our exprets

Answer (score 0):

Where is your **madeAjaxCall**() in js file??

I think you are trying to do this

```
<input type="button" value="Ajax Submit" onclick="hello();">
```

your code looks fine.

Comment: Can you please see my project structure ?

Comment: Add $(document).ready(function() { alert("test") }); in your js file, if alert fire you will come to know js is included in your jsp.

Comment: No use.Is this right to access the file     `<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>` and 
    `<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/hello.js"></script>`

Comment: Remove first slash and try like this <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> in both.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this can help you (place it in your dispatcher xml):

```xml
<mvc:resources location="jquery/**" mapping="jquery/**" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try using c tag library

```
<%@ taglib prefix='c' uri='http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt'%>
```

and script tags as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></c:url>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="/jquery/hello.js"></c:url>'></script>
```

**Also** check if you have configured your dispatcher servlet to handle all requests using following url pattern

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

then you need to add tag shown by @Dani